# When running slather i see ruby error bad interpreter error

Tags: ruby, bamboo, slather

I'm trying to get the coverage result of the tests for IOS. I use the `slather coverage` command. But I keep getting the error

> /Users/bamboo/.gem/bin/slather: /Users/bamboo/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

When I run the `whereis ruby` command on the agent, I see the following result

```
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1
```

Could you please write me how to change the path to ruby for slather from the task Bamboo pipeline? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ruby `3.1.0` has not been installed with rbenv on your system yet.

Run:

1. `rbenv install 3.1.0`
2. `bundle install` in your project directory if there is a `Gemfile`
3. `slather coverage`.